# png image viewer that shows tEXt metadata

Tags: windows, image-viewer, png

I am looking for a simple image viewer for PNGs that also displays the metadata encoded within the image (png tEXt chunks).

It needs to:

- support most PNG image types (but MUST support viewing **16bit grayscale**).
- show the **standard tEXt** chunks (from png spec; Title, Author, Description, etc).
- show **non-standard tEXt** chunks in the file (bonus if it also displays iTxt and zTxt as well).
- run on **Windows 7** and up (but even better if its cross-platform).
- be free for personal use (but even better if its open source).

I am currently using a utility called TweakPNG (http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/) to view this tEXt (along with the other chunks), and this meets my particular needs just fine.

What I really need is an image viewer that I can recommend to others (that I work with) who also need to view this metadata. It needs to be friendly, easy to use, and oriented for viewing images - nothing that looks like a developer's tool.